# Computing weighted average on a deque using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, deque

I have a deque object whose weighted average I would like to find. The deque object is a collection of (60 * 60 * 3) NumPy arrays (They are actually images stored in deque object). I would like to find the weighted average of all the elements(i.e images) in the deque object.

```
motion_buffer = deque(maxlen = 5)
motion_weights = [5./15, 4./15, 3./15, 2./15, 1./15]
# After adding few elements ( i.e images ) in motion_buffer. the following is done:
motion_avg = np.average(motion_buffer, weights=motion_weights)

I get the error:
    "Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights "
    TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

I understand there is a mismatch somewhere but supplying axis values ( as per [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html)) did not help me. I have tested it in the following manner:

```
>>> A = np.random.randn(4,4)
>>> weights = [1 , 4 ,6 ,7]
>>> buf = deque(maxlen=5)
>>> buf.appendleft(A)
>>> c = np.average(buf, weights=weights)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...  
    "Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights "
TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

I have tried using np.average for deque object with 1d elements and it works.
How exactly should I modify my code, I experimented but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't see where you supply axis values.  `np.average(buf, ...)` will first convert `np.array(buf)`.  Check that, especially its `shape`.  If the `deque` has 5 items, and you have 5 weights, I think you need to specify `axis=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `np.average` documentation

> weights : array_like, optional
>     An array of weights associated with the values in `a`. Each value in
>     `a` contributes to the average according to its associated weight.
>     The weights array **can either be 1-D (in which case its length must be**
>     **the size of `a` along the given axis)** or of the same shape as `a`.

you can't.

You can implement a workaround

```
av_average  = np.average(np.average(your_deque, axis=(1,2,3)), weights=(5,4,3,2,1))
```

where you first (the inner average) mediate each `60×60×3`matrix specifying the axis on which to sum and later using the weights to compute the weighted average of the averages.

---

The OP really wants this

```
average = np.average(the_deque, axis=0, weights=(…))
```

where `(…)` is a sequence whose length equals the current length of the deque.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but maybe I have not written clearly, but the average output should be of size 60*60*3. But perhaps specifying axis will result in taking average within the image matrix itself, which I do not want. It's like if images are x,y,z; then output should be like (x + y + z) / 3. However I do not want this average but a weighted average

Answer (score 0):

One way which worked, is converting deque to numpy array and then

```
my_array = np.array(deque)
np.average(deque, axis=0, weights=weights)
```

helped with the only problem of increase of computational time.

Comment: You do not need to convert your deque to an array, Numpy does it for you — the first executable line of `average` is `a = np.asanyarray(a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: from collections import deque                                                                
In [2]: >>> A = np.random.randn(4,4) 
   ...: >>> weights = [1 , 4 ,6 ,7] 
   ...: >>> buf = deque(maxlen=5) 
   ...: >>> buf.appendleft(A)                                                                        
In [3]: buf                                                                                          
Out[3]: 
deque([array([[ 1.10651806, -0.50125715, -0.35877456,  1.31969932],
              [-0.4674734 ,  0.25144544, -1.5392525 ,  0.09607722],
              [ 2.24245413, -1.09636901,  1.97502862, -0.90069983],
              [ 0.61917197, -0.13276115, -0.1103521 ,  0.56556319]])])
In [4]: np.array(buf)                                                                                
Out[4]: 
array([[[ 1.10651806, -0.50125715, -0.35877456,  1.31969932],
        [-0.4674734 ,  0.25144544, -1.5392525 ,  0.09607722],
        [ 2.24245413, -1.09636901,  1.97502862, -0.90069983],
        [ 0.61917197, -0.13276115, -0.1103521 ,  0.56556319]]])
In [5]: np.average(buf, weights=weights, axis=0)                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8a8c3dba2415> in <module>
----> 1 np.average(buf, weights=weights, axis=0)

<__array_function__ internals> in average(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
    399             if wgt.shape[0] != a.shape[axis]:
    400                 raise ValueError(
--> 401                     "Length of weights not compatible with specified axis.")
    402 
    403             # setup wgt to broadcast along axis

ValueError: Length of weights not compatible with specified axis.
In [6]: _4.shape                                                                                     
Out[6]: (1, 4, 4)
```

Oops, I should have checked the shape of the array.  For some reason, which I won't dig into `Out[4]` has an initial size 1 dimension.

```
In [7]: np.average(buf, weights=weights, axis=1)                                                     
Out[7]: array([[ 0.94586406, -0.38905653,  0.25344014,  0.01437508]])
```